# How to display localized date?

Tags: xslt, localization, internationalization

How do i have XSLT display a *localized* date to the user (in the locale of the user-agent).

For example, given an xml `date` in ISO format (`2013-09-04T10:46:19.658`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Stuff>
   <Created>2013-09-04T10:46:19.658</Created>
</Stuff>
```

And the beginnings of a stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5.0" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>
   <xsl:template match="/Stuff">
   <html>
   <body>
       Created: <xsl:value-of select="format-date('Created')"/>
   </body>
   </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The desired output depends, of course, on the locale of the user-agent (e.g. the client's browser):

```
Created: 01/11/34
Created: 05.09.13
Created: 05.09.2013
Created: 05/09 2013
Created: 05/09/2013
Created: 05-09-13
Created: 05-09-2013
Created: 09.05.2013
Created: 09/05/2013
Created: 13.09.05
Created: 2013.09.05
Created: 2013.09.05.
Created: 2013/09/05
Created: 2013/9/5
Created: 2013-09-05
Created: 2013-9-5
Created: 29/10/34
Created: 5. 9. 2013
Created: 5.09.2013
Created: 5.9.2013
Created: 5.9.2013 г.
Created: 5.9.2013.
Created: 5//09//2013
Created: 5/09/2013
Created: 5/9/2013
Created: 5/9/2556
Created: 5-9-2013
Created: 9/5/2013
```

Does XSLT support localization?

## It runs on the client

The transformation of XML into HTML happens on the client. Since the transformation happens on the client, the client (obviously) knows its own locale.

For example, the client is given some `xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/Styles/Contoso_Handheld.xslt' media='handheld'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/Styles/Contoso_iPhone.xslt' media='only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/Styles/Contoso.xslt' media='all'?>
<Stuff>
   <Created>2013-09-04T10:46:19.658</Created>
</Stuff>
```

Notice the lines where the client in instructed which `XSLT` to use.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/Styles/Contoso_Handheld.xslt' media='handheld'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/Styles/Contoso_iPhone.xslt' media='only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/Styles/Contoso.xslt' media='all'?>
```

The *User-Agent* fetches the XSLT, transforms the XML, and displays it to the user. All this processing happens in the locale of the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard XSLT 1.0 does not have any function to localize dates.

XSLT 2.0 has date and date-time formatting functions supporting localizations: see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-format-date) but the implementation can vary - for example Saxon seem not to implement the calendar / language part.

Specific XSLT implementation have extension function supporting date-time localization - see for example [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256099.aspx).

Even if you have a formatting function supporting localization you will still have the problem of find and pass the correct locale - if the XSLT is running on the server and the result is rendered in a browser the locale of the server could be the wrong one, and so you'll need to extract the locale information from the HTTP headers or with some JavaScript and use it on the server.